# Sharing objects between applications

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to share an object between two GAE apps. The first will have the class's file, and will offer up an instance of that object. The second, using a given url, will access the first app, get the object and then use is. Is this actually possible? If so what am I not doing right in the code below?

As a small side note I tried a solution with pickle, but both apps are required to have the class in its name space, but I will be working with a number of these. I thought about trying to imitate something like Java's abstract class by using inheritance, but that didn't work out. I can provide that code too if you want to see it.

- I understand the possible Terms of Service, that is not a issue.
- I know cloud computing is out there, I don't know how to work with it, and I would
  prefer to avoid the costs because I am developing this as a class project.
- I have seen some suggestions to use remote_api, but I have seen no good example
  of how it can be used, let alone used to allow two applications to interact.
- I have seen the solution to use multiple versions, but each student will have
  an app, it would be incredibly messy, but possibly doable.

**First.Py:**

```
class SampleCritter():
    def move():
        ...
class Access(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        CritStore(stats=self.request.body).put()

    def get(self):
        creature = CritStore.all().order('-date').get()
        if creature:
            stats = loads(creature.stats)
            return SampleCritter(stats)
        else:
            return SampleCritter()
```

**Second.py:**

```
class Out(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        url = self.request.POST['url']
        critter = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        critter.move()
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't share objects between apps.

The longer answer is, your first app can expose objects using an HTTP based API.  Any client can access the HTTP API, including app 2.

App 2 will have to manipulate objects via the HTTP API.  You won't be able to call `critter.move()` from app 2, though if you create a handler say, `critter\move`, you can have the handler pull up the appropriate Critter instance and call move() on it.  You'll have to pass all the appropriate params via HTTP POST as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite out of my depth with this what do you mean by 'create a handler say, critter\move' and the rest?

Comment: Creating a request handler is elementary stuff in App Engine.  Creating multiple apps is going to be a major distraction to you.  Focus on how to get a single app working first.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure i follow. Are you saying turn the critter into the app so that each page in the app is a function. For example critter.com would could return some values the. Critter.com/move would some how return the move function. Is that what you mean?

Comment: More over what does "expose objects using an HTTP based API" mean? I have done very little work with HTTP, do you know about a good resource that explains how to use HTTP in conjunction with python?

Comment: It's all very simple and straightforward.  You're just imagining that there's some magical fairy dust that will make everything work automagically.  There isn't.  HTTP requests cannot return python functions.  You have to manually write an http request handler (you've already written a few request handlers), such that when the url is accessed, the handler code will fetch the appropriate critter  instance, and then call move().  You can pass in parameters and return the result, but you can't pass the python object around.